# Is it possible to add directives in an *ngFor in angular2?

Tags: angular

My scenario is that I want to dynamically add content to the page in an `*ngFor` and have the components render.  If I add the components directly they will render properly so I know I have all the correct imports and such.  When I add a collection and add the definitions in a loop I can see them if I inspect the page but they do not render the component.

I've tried various life cycle events, followed some advice on other questions but not making any progress.

Any help is appreciated.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'case-based-search-navigation',
    directives: [NgClass, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ClinicalComponent],
    template: 
 `
<ul id="sidebar-wrapper" class="clearfix nav navbar-default sidebar-nav clearfix">
    <li *ngFor="#item of navigationItems" [ngClass]="item"></li>
</ul>
`,
})

export class NavigationComponent {
    public navigationItems : Array<string> = [];

    constructor() {
       this.navigationItems.push('clinical');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector : '.clinical',
    directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: 
`
test loading components
`
})

export class ClinicalComponent {

}
```

Comment: Did you miss to add class `<li class="clinical" ...>` or you're expecting `item` to be "clinical"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this required the use of the DynamicComponentLoader.  The most ideal solution did not work.  The below will render the component without any angular bindings like click, or router link. In the `*ngFor` I built up the proper output with a `ngClass` value. Hopefully this is a bug because this is a much cleaner solution than what does work.

```
 ngOnInit () {
        this.navigationService.navigationSections.forEach((item) => {
             this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(item.type, '.' + item.key, this.injector);
        })
    }
```

The below code does work in loading the items dynamically.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'case-based-search-navigation',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template:
    `
<ul id="sidebar-wrapper" class="clearfix nav navbar-default sidebar-nav clearfix">
  <div #sidebar></div>
</ul>
`,
})

export class NavigationComponent {

    constructor(      
        private navigationService: NavigationService,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.navigationService.navigationSections.forEach((item) => {
            this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(item.type, this.elementRef, 'sidebar');
        })
    }
}
```

The components are added in another component.  The idea here is that the list of components will be loaded based on user preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think as default it wont add it as it doesn't detect the change. You have to create a new array of navigationItems and it will rerender it.